# Multiple references in separate lists; Python

Tags: python, list, reference, immutability, mutable

I'm trying to basically create references to plot multiple relationships and store them in a list or possibly a dictionary.

Basically:

`variable1 = 10`

//in this case, 'ref' denotes that the variable should be a reference)
`listA = [variable1(ref), variable2, variable3]

listB = [variable1(ref), variable4, variable5]`

`for i in listA:

  i = i + 10`

`for i in listB:

  i = i + 10`

`print listA[0]`
//Should print 30

`print listB[0]`
//Should print 30

How can I split two references to the same variable into two separate lists?

Comment: yes with mutables, no with immutables

Comment: What about two lists, each containing keys of the same collection, say dictionary?

Comment: tcaswell, could you be more specific. What would be the syntax? Is there a mutable/immutable command?

Comment: jedwards, could you show me how you would do it with a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about two lists, each containing keys of the same collection, say dictionary?

For example:

```
MASTER = [10,11,12,13,14]

LISTA = [0,1,2]
LISTB = [0,3,4]

for i in LISTA: MASTER[i] += 10
for i in LISTB: MASTER[i] += 10

print MASTER[LISTA[0]]

print MASTER[LISTB[0]]
```

[ideone example](http://ideone.com/lD7oky)

Or using a wrapper class:

```
class SharedInt:
    val = None
    def __init__(self, v): self.val = v

    def __add__(self, a): 
        self.val += a
        return self.val

    def __int__(self): return self.val

v1 = SharedInt(10)

listA = [v1, 11, 12]
listB = [v1, 13, 14]

for i in listA: i += 10
for i in listB: i += 10

print int(listA[0])
print int(listB[0])
```

[ideone example](http://ideone.com/XWeE)

Lastly, or using embedded lists:

```
v1 = [10]

listA = [v1, 11, 12]
listB = [v1, 13, 14]

for i in listA: 
    if isinstance(i, list): i[0] += 10 
    else: i += 10
for i in listB: 
    if isinstance(i, list): i[0] += 10 
    else: i += 10

print listA[0]
print listB[0]
```

[ideone example](http://ideone.com/PrTq2L)

Note that the first example treats *all* of your ListX members as "references" while the last two examples treats the members as "values", unless you make them `SharedInt()`s or enclose them in a list respectively.

In other words,

```
LISTA[1] = 21 # First example
ListA[1] = 11 # Second, third examples
```

Comment: Those both work but I was looking for a cleaner command because this would become a nightmare in the program I'm writing.

Is there a way to set the type of variable to mutable, immutable? Otherwise I may just have to use a dictionary.

Comment: Well, ints will always be passed "by value" (in fact, a reference to an immutable object), so you have to do something to make that not happen.  Wrapping it in a list (example 3) is a common technique, but it's not possible to pass it "by reference" as just a standard int.

Comment: [This related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/python-passing-an-integer-by-reference) has some more discussion, but the outcome is the same unfortunately.

Comment: If I set it as a dictionary, it becomes as a 'reference' no matter where it is stored, right? All of the objects of a dictionary point back to a single variable?

Comment: Not exactly like that.  For example `d = {'var1':10, 'var2':11, 'var3':12}` defines a dictionary with three entries.  Something like `d['var1'] += 10` will increment the value associated with the key `var1` by 10.  But `x=d['var1']; x+=10` will not -- `d['var1'] `will remain unchanged.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make multiple keys to a single dictionary value?

Comment: Not easily.  The easy approach would be to map your multiple keys to a single "master" key (using one dictionary), then map your master key to a value using a second dictionary (or list).  Alternatively, you could create your own class that did what you wanted, which wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I'm not too fond of classes, but maybe just a list of functions overwrite the value when called. Could you give an example of your master key method?