# swap function output is different from what expected

Tags: python, scope, swap, jes

I think the output should be `x = 5`, `y = 3`. But, when I tried executing it in jes it shows that `x=3` and `y=5`.

My swap function is as follows:

```
def swap (x,y):    
    temp=x
    x=y
    y=temp
```

And from my driver function I call `swap()`:

```
def driver():    
    x=3
    y=5
    swap(x,y)
    print x
    print y
```

I want to know why isn't the output as expected?

Comment: I don't believe this question is a duplicate of the one it is marked as. This question has more to do about scoping and basic function functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Well this is not a big issue in python you can return multiple values like try this snippet it might help you.

```
def swap(a,b):
   return (b,a)

def driver(x,y):
    print "Previous x=",x,"y=",y
    x,y = swap(x,y)
    print "Now x=", x, "y=",y

driver(3,5)
```

Comment: why my answer is downvoted, It answers the question. The person who asked question just mentioned that swap is not working so I just gave him a working snippet.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have suggested, this really doesn't require functions. Since you have decided to use them though, you might as well try and understand a bit more about [scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules).

In order to **retain** the swapped values you need to **return** them or else they *get lost* after the execution of `swap()`:

```
def swap (x,y):
    temp=x
    x=y
    y=temp
    return x, y  # must return the swapped values.
```

Then, in the function where you call `swap()` you assign the returned values to the variables that you swapped:

```
def driver():
    x=3
    y=5
    x, y = swap(x,y)  # re-assign values
    print x
    print y
```

Running `driver()` now will give you the swapped value:

```
5
3
```

This happens because in the function `swap()` the variables `x` and `y` you pass as arguments are treated as local to that function, only `swap` can see their value. If you don't return this value back, it is lost and forgotten.

Answer (score -1):

Integers are immutable in python.  You are setting `y` to `x` and `x` to `y` in the local scope, but are not modifying the reference to the initial integers passed in. In python, the best you can do if you want to encapsulate a `swap` function that modifies in-place instead of by return is pass some kind of container object that is mutable and contain references to the thing you want to swap:

```
def swap(container):
    container[0], container[1] = container[1], container[0]
```

And then call it like so:

```
x = 3
y = 5
container = [x,y]
swap(container)
```

FWIW, swap in python can be implemented in one line as simply as:

```
x, y = y, x
```

Which is probably syntactically clearer in most cases anyway.

See also [Python passing an integer by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/python-passing-an-integer-by-reference)

Answer (score -1):

In python assignment changes the identity of an object rather than its value (unless you are mutating the content). This is worth noting that, as per [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#data-model)

> Every object has an identity, a type and a value.

So interchanging the identities inside `swap` would not change the identity inside the `driver`. Moreover, python does not allow you to change the value of an immutable types so, there is no other possible ways to swap the values inside the `swap` method.

Comment: @Downvoter, do you have a problem understanding `Python Data Model`?

Comment: I'm not the down voter but I'd say this answer is difficult to understand and of little use to the OP who is clearly a beginner.

Comment: @PaulRooney: But this is a concept every beginner needs to know (vouching on the fact that I was a beginner myself). But then it is a perspective