# Python: Change an element in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 lists:

```
one = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [2, 3, 4, 5],
    [3, 4, 5, 6],
    [4, 5, 6, 7]
    ]

two = [
    [one[0][0], one[0][1], one[1][0], one[1][1]],
    [one[0][2], one[0][3], one[1][2], one[1][3]],
    [one[2][0], one[2][1], one[3][0], one[3][1]],
    [one[2][2], one[2][3], one[3][2], one[3][3]]
    ]
```

When I input this one:

```
two[0][0] = 9
```

It comes out like this:

```
one: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
two: [[9, 2, 2, 3], [3, 4, 4, 5], [3, 4, 4, 5], [5, 6, 6, 7]]
```

How can I get the same changes as in 'two' list in 'one' list when I changes the element in 'two' list, so that:

```
one: [[9, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
two: [[9, 2, 2, 3], [3, 4, 4, 5], [3, 4, 4, 5], [5, 6, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: This is a great question! Generally people want the opposite of what you're asking for!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You can't really do that since integers are immutable in Python. The only way would be some ugly workaround by making a list out of each number  or something similar... so that you end up with references instead of value

Comment: why not just two = one, so when you change one, you get changed two too?

Comment: Oops, my mistake on output of 'two' list. I already edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue here as other explained is that int objects are immutable
So doing

```
two[0][0] = 9
```

wont change the old two[0][0] object instead it will create new object and make two[0][0] reference this new object (the old object is garbage collected if not other reference it in this case there is)

and to be more clear in this case after creating both arrays we have the following (--> means reference)

```
one[0][0] --> object(1)
two[0][0] --> object(1)
```

then when you excuted

```
two[0][0] = 9
```

the object reference looks like this

```
one[0][0] --> object(1)
two[0][0] --> object(9)
```

So to solve this we need to change the values that you have in the array to be mutable

I have created very simple class that hold the int and made the array out of it and that resolves your issue

here is working code

```
class IntHolder:
    def __init__(self,int_value):
        self.intvalue = int_value
    def set_value(self,int_value):
        self.intvalue = int_value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.intvalue)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.intvalue)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.intvalue)
one = [
    [IntHolder(1), IntHolder(2), IntHolder(3), IntHolder(4)],
    [IntHolder(2), IntHolder(3), IntHolder(4), IntHolder(5)],
    [IntHolder(3), IntHolder(4), IntHolder(5), IntHolder(6)],
    [IntHolder(4), IntHolder(5), IntHolder(6), IntHolder(7)]
    ]

two = [
    [one[0][0], one[0][1], one[1][0], one[1][1]],
    [one[0][2], one[0][3], one[1][2], one[1][3]],
    [one[2][0], one[2][1], one[3][0], one[3][1]],
    [one[2][2], one[2][3], one[3][2], one[3][3]]
    ]
two[0][0].set_value(9)

print one
print two
```

Answer (score 1):

Integers are immutable in python.  One approach you can take is to enclose the integers in a container type (list) and modify the container values.

See these additional pointers for related details:

[Python passing an integer by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/python-passing-an-integer-by-reference)

[How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

You're actually copying the values.

Copy the reference to the lists in one:

```
two=[one[0], one[1], one[2], one[3]]
```

Then you get for `two[0][0]=9`:

```
one == [[9, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
two == [[9, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: This answer changes the structure of the list `two`. It just happens to give the same output for this specific set of numbers. Note that the OP's original `two` is divided into four "quadrants" that contain the numbers from `one[0], one[1], one[2], one[3]` , not four lines.

Comment: Indeed, i did not saw what the indices are exactly doing. Then i would suggest writing a wrapper class, where ``__getitem__`` returns the correct value from the list ``one``. May be the easiest and most flexible way, with respect to larger matrices in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

```
def listfix(one, two):
    if one != two:
        one = two
    return one, two

two[0][0]=9
one, two = listfix(one, two)
```