# Program not terminating when score limit is reached?

Tags: python

I'm working on a simple text-based trivia game as my first python project, and my program won't terminate once the score limit is reached.

```
def game(quest_list):
    points = 0
    score_limit = 20

    x, y = info()
    time.sleep(2)

    if y >= 18 and y < 100:
        time.sleep(1)
        while points < score_limit:
            random.choice(quest_list)(points)
            time.sleep(2)
            print("Current score:", points, "points")
        print("You beat the game!")
        quit()
    ...
```

Comment: `points` is never incremented and so the loop will never terminate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `points` variable is not increased. Something like this might work in your inner loop:

```
    while points < score_limit:
        points = random.choice(quest_list)(points)
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Current score:", points, "points")
```

I'm assuming that `quest_list` is a list of functions, and you're passing the `points` value as an argument? To make this example work, you'll also want to return the points from the function returned by the `quest_list` that's called. A perhaps cleaner way to build this would be to return only the points generated by the quest. Then you could do something like:

```
        quest = random.choice(quest_list)
        points += quest()
```

Unless `points` is a mutable data structure, it won't change the value. You can read more about that in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/python-passing-an-integer-by-reference).