# Python--Function not returning value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function to compare two values, val1 and val2, and if val1 is larger than val2, add 1 point to a_points (Think of it like Team A) and vice versa (add one point to b_points if val2 is larger.) 
If the two values are even I won't add any points to a_points or b_points.

My problem is **test_val will not return the values of a_points or b_points.**

```
a_points=0
b_points=0

def test_val(a_points,b_points,val1,val2):
    if val1 > val2:
        a_points+=1
        return a_points
    elif val2 > val1:
        b_points+=1
        return b_points
    elif val1==val2:
         pass
```

[Here's a link to a visualization showing the problem.](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a0%3D5%0Aa1%3D6%0Aa2%3D7%0Ab0%3D3%0Ab1%3D6%0Ab2%3D10%0Aa_points%3D0%0Ab_points%3D0%0A%0Adef%20test_val(a_points,b_points,val1,val2%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20val1%20%3E%20val2%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a_points%2B%3D1%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20a_points%0A%20%20%20%20elif%20val2%20%3E%20val1%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b_points%2B%3D1%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20b_points%0A%20%20%20%20elif%20val1%3D%3Dval2%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pass%0A%0Atest_val(a_points,b_points,a0,b0%29%0Atest_val(a_points,b_points,a1,b1%29%0Atest_val(a_points,b_points,a2,b2%29%0A%0Aprint(a_points,b_points%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=13&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: As shown in your visualization, `a_points` and `b_points` inside the function aren't the same as the global variables. So modifying them inside the function won't modify the global ones. You might be interested in the `global` keyword (aka add `global a_points, b_points`) or in the `return` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this:

```
a0=5
a1=6
a2=7
b0=3
b1=6
b2=10
a_points=0
b_points=0

def test_val(a_points, b_points, val1, val2):
    if val1 > val2:
        a_points += 1
        return (a_points, b_points)
    elif val2 > val1:
        b_points += 1
        return (a_points, b_points)
    elif val1==val2:
        return (a_points, b_points)

a_points, b_points = test_val(a_points,b_points, a0, b0)
a_points, b_points = test_val(a_points,b_points, a1, b1)
a_points, b_points = test_val(a_points,b_points, a2, b2)

print(a_points, b_points)
```

Good luck!

Comment: I think returning both values as Sebastian suggests is the best solution. This way the function has always the same output. I would put only one `return (a_points, b_points)` at the end of the function and remove the `elif` statement, but these are just minor enhancements (as Gormador posted just now)

Comment: Very easy to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are generally a **bad idea**. Don't use them unless you really have to.

The proper way to implement such counter is to use a class.

```
class MyCounter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a_points = 0
        self.b_points = 0

    def test_val(self, val1, val2):
        if val1 > val2:
            self.a_points += 1
        elif val2 > val1:
            self.b_points += 1
        else:
            pass

counter = MyCounter()
counter.test_val(1, 2)
counter.test_val(1, 3)
counter.test_val(5, 3)
print(counter.a_points, counter.b_points)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2)
```

Note that returning a value from `test_val` doesn't make sense, because caller has no way to know if she gets `a_points` or `b_points`, so she can't use return value in any meaningful way.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wanted to do! I **tried** to make it into a class before but I failed and then the above-mentioned problem happened and I felt it was best to keep it simple.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @KristenHuber You can upvote my answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
a_points=0
b_points=0

def test_val(a_points,b_points,val1,val2):
    global a_points
    global b_points

    if val1 > val2:
        a_points+=1
        return a_points
    elif val2 > val1:
        b_points+=1
        return b_points

    elif val1==val2:
         # If you pass, it won't return a_points nor b_points
         return a_points # or b_points
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print (test_val(a_points,b_points,1,2))
print (test_val(a_points,b_points,2,1))
print (test_val(a_points,b_points,2,2))
```

This will give you a result:

```
1
1
None
```

Hence you should not look at the function to return values, rather it updates the values of variables a_points and b_points. That is why in the link that you shared the code includes a `print(a_points,b_points)` statement at the end

Answer (score 0):

This will simplify your code and logic. And make it work ;-)

```
a0=5
a1=6
a2=7
b0=3
b1=6
b2=10
a_points=0
b_points=0

def test_val(a_points,b_points,val1,val2):
    if val1 > val2:
        a_points+=1

    elif val2 > val1:
        b_points+=1

    return a_points, b_points



a_points, b_points = test_val(a_points,b_points,a0,b0)
a_points, b_points = test_val(a_points,b_points,a1,b1)
a_points, b_points = test_val(a_points,b_points,a2,b2)

print(a_points,b_points)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the that Python integers are immutable which in general is good to read about. A few more details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15148557/3727050).

Now, regarding solutions:

1. As suggested, you can use `global` variables. Keep in mind this is usually considered bad practice cause it leads to messy code... but `global`s have their place in programming.
2. Also suggested, you can always return both `a_points` and `b_points`
3. Use `list`s to keep score:

   - The `test_val` will return either 0, 1 or 2 where 0 means equal, 1 means the first argument is larger and 2 means the second argument is larger.
   - Your main script will have a list with the above indexes where it will "keep score"

The code:

```
a0=5
a1=6
a2=7
b0=3
b1=6
b2=10
points=[0, 0, 0]


def test_val(val1,val2):
    if val1 > val2:
        return 1
    elif val2 > val1:
        return 2
    elif val1==val2:
        return 0

points[test_val(a0,b0)] += 1
points[test_val(a1,b1)] += 1
points[test_val(a2,b2)] += 1

print("eq=%d, A=%d, B=%d" % (points[0], points[1], points[2]))
```

Output ([visualize](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a0%3D5%0Aa1%3D6%0Aa2%3D7%0Ab0%3D3%0Ab1%3D6%0Ab2%3D10%0Apoints%3D%5B0,%200,%200%5D%0A%0A%0Adef%20test_val(val1,val2%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20val1%20%3E%20val2%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%0A%20%20%20%20elif%20val2%20%3E%20val1%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%202%0A%20%20%20%20elif%20val1%3D%3Dval2%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%0A%0Apoints%5Btest_val(a0,b0%29%5D%20%2B%3D%201%0Apoints%5Btest_val(a1,b1%29%5D%20%2B%3D%201%0Apoints%5Btest_val(a2,b2%29%5D%20%2B%3D%201%0A%0Aprint(%22eq%3D%25d,%20A%3D%25d,%20B%3D%25d%22%20%25%20(points%5B0%5D,%20points%5B1%5D,%20points%5B2%5D%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=27&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false))

```
eq=1, A=1, B=1
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

Note that `a_points` and `b_points` shadow your global variables, since they are also passed as parameters.

Any way, you are not returning value in case of equality, instead of `pass`, return a value

```
def test_val(a_points,b_points,val1,val2):
    if val1 > val2:
        a_points+=1
        return a_points
    elif val2 > val1:
        b_points+=1
        return b_points
    elif val1==val2:
         return a_points
```