# 'Return' function doesn't return variable python

Tags: python-3.x

Essentially, the variable 'exists' doesn't return. The output is "false, true, false," but I cannot see why it should be. As can be seen from the code, I have tried making the variable 'exists' `global` to no effect.

I've looked around and found two similar questions- [Python--Function not returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762324/python-function-not-returning-value), [Python: Return possibly not returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347740/python-return-possibly-not-returning-value/53348238), but cannot understand why my code doesn't work.

I'm aware that this question is very specific- if it's a silly mistake I've missed then I'll remove it, if it's a Python caveat then I'll see whether I can rephrase it.

```
import time
global exists
exists= False

def in_thread(exists):

    print(exists)
    time.sleep(2)
    exists= True
    print(exists)
    return(exists)

in_thread(exists)
print(exists)
```

Comment: If you modify the value of a global variable, you need to call it at the beginning of your function. It might be a part of the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `exists` inside of `in_thread` is a different variable from the `exists` outside.  If you want to use the same variable, use the `global` keyword:

```
exists = False

def somefunction():
    global exists
    exists = True

print(exists)
someFunction()
print(exists)
# False
# True
```

Also, `in_thread` looks like it's not returning anything because you're not assigning the result to anything (you're just printing a local version of `exists`).

Answer (score 5):

You really should consider rewriting your function to be as such:

```
import time

def in_thread():
    exists = False
    print(exists)
    time.sleep(2)
    exists = True
    return(exists)


print(in_thread())
```

It is returning, but it's returning its own version of exists when you declare exists outside the function. Instead consider creating it inside the function and call it in a print statement so it prints the output from the return.

This will lead to the output:

```
False
True
```

If you want to use your original function as written, you need to change your call to be in a print statement so you print the returned value:

```
import time
global exists
exists= False

def in_thread(exists):

    print(exists)
    time.sleep(2)
    exists= True
    print(exists)
    return(exists)

print(in_thread(exists))
```

Answer (score 0):

print(exists) returns the global variable value which is set to False.

To print the value from you function, you would need to call the function inside of print()   print(in-thread(exists))

Replace:
  in_thread(exists)
  print(exists)

With:
  print(in_thread(exists))