# Accessing variables by reference in python

Tags: python, pointers, reference

I am not sure if this makes any sense in python, but consider I have two variables `x` and `y`:

```
x = 1
y = x
```

Now, at a later time when I change `x`, I want `y` to see this change. that is if I do

```
x = 2
```

I want `y` to be 2 also. Is there a way to do `reference(x) = 2`, so that all variables that were assigned to `x`  will see this change?

One way to make this work is to use lists for everything as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/passing-an-integer-by-reference-in-python). This would work if I had defined `x` as list, so if

```
x = [1]
y = x
```

then, doing `x.clear()` and `x.append(val) for val in new_list` would work, and `y` will change according to the new list.

But I would like to do it for any type, because otherwise I will need to revisit most of my codebase. Is there a mutable type so I don't have to redefine all my `y`'s to be `x[0]`.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you would really want this semantic. Are you refactoring code from another language or something?

Comment: To put it in context, I have a `PyQt` tableView where its model has some data. Now, the model's data (type or value) might be changed by the user at any time. I have threads running in the background which use the table's model data from the program start. If a user changes the data, I would rather it be reflected automatically in the other threads and classes without rereading the model.

Comment: I don't understand you problem that much. You means the `y=copy.deepcopy(x)`？

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an integer by reference in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/passing-an-integer-by-reference-in-python)

Comment: @damores not really... I mentioned that answer as possible solution, but i was looking for something different. I suppose the lazy way out I am asking for is just not possible.

Comment: Just use a dictionary and pass it around.

Comment: You cannot do this in Python (unless you feel like doing some serious hacking of the interpreter)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps make a small wrapper class for your values? The object containing the value is then passed "by reference".

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

x = Wrapper(5)
y = x

print(x.value, y.value)
x.value = 3
print(x.value, y.value)
```

Output:

```
5 5
3 3
```