# python variable range with different type

Tags: python-2.7

[image]

anyone can explain why when we declare as list, it will cross different method, but if declare as int, it can only use inside of method.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't screenshot your code. Add it as raw text and then format using the `{}` code format button. It makes it easier for people to read and test and means that search engines can index it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an integer by reference in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/passing-an-integer-by-reference-in-python)

Comment: Please provide your code not an image. Read through (How to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

In the example where you have `l` and `n` as ints, you aren't actually modifying `l` or `n` before you print them. You are incrementing `p` and `k` but then since `p` and `k` aren't assigned to anything you are throwing the computation away.

Additionally, `ints` in Python are immutable. So, if you wanted to store an updated value, your class should have properties that you update accordingly such as `self.l` and `self.n`.