# Python how to mutate a variable in a method call

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

Is it possible to modify variables in if statements, loops, and function calls in Python like you can in C and Java?

Ex:

```
i=0
while((i+=1)<10): #invalid syntax
    print(i)
```

If not why is that?

Comment: Integers are immutable.

Comment: These two examples are not the same. I doubt the first one is allowed in C and/orJava

Comment: And no, Python does not allow expressions as `if` conditions, only statements.

Comment: afaik `int y=x+=6` works fine in c land

Comment: @JoranBeasley it probably does, but this is not what OP is asking

Comment: @DeepSpace the first example is allowed in Java I tried it before I posted. I know the second example is allowed in C.

Comment: @DeepSpace https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/MassiveNavyblueSpreadsheet

Comment: @JoranBeasley I stand corrected then :) But the answer to the actual question is still "no, neither is allowed in Python"

Comment: this[https://stackoverflow.com/a/15148557/1176331] could help you understand although you seem to have found the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as the datatype is mutable

```
def modified(data):
    data['a'] = 5

x = {'b':7}
modified(x)
print(x)


def increment_a(data):
    data['a'] += 1
    return data['a']

x = {'a':1}
while increment_a(x) < 10:
    print(x)
```

however strings and integers are immutable

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP is asking.