# Modifying a list to copy another without making a copy of the original

Tags: python, list

I have a program which is an implementation of a sorting algorithm

```
def myfunction(data):
    x = [sorted elements...]
```

Input

```
mylist = [elements...]
myfunction(mylist)
print(mylist)
```

The function ends up eventually with a list x, with the same elements which have been sorted, but is a copy of mylist. This means that when the program is run, mylist is returned, instead of x.

How can I alter mylist within myfunction so that is the same as x? Surely there is a way to map x and mylist to each other and then iteratively alter mylist until it matches x?

Comment: Related: [Passing an integer by reference in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/passing-an-integer-by-reference-in-python)

Comment: Why would you want to iterative change it? Why not just `return x ` and then write `myList = myfunction(myList)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def myfunction(data):
    x = [sorted elements...]
    data[:] = x
```

This modifies `data` in-place and sets it to whatever values `x` contains.