# Updating variables in recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

This is referring to this leetcode question here: https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-iii/

Basically I am given a binary tree in which each node contains an integer value. I have to find the number of paths that sum to a given value.

Building up a sample tree here

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

root = TreeNode(12)
root.left = TreeNode(7)
root.right = TreeNode(1)
root.left.left = TreeNode(4)

root.right.left = TreeNode(10)
root.right.right = TreeNode(5)
```

This is my solution using recursion

```
def count_paths(root, S):

    cache = {0:1}

    def helper(node, S:int, curr_path:int, cache:dict, result:int):

        if not node:
            return result

        curr_path += node.val
        prev_path = curr_path - S

        result += cache.get(prev_path, 0)
        cache[curr_path] = cache.get(curr_path, 0) + 1

        my_node = None
        if node != None:
            my_node = node.val 

        print("node: {}, curr: {}, prev: {}".format(my_node, curr_path, prev_path))                
        print(cache)
        print(result)

        helper(node.left, S, curr_path, cache, result)
        helper(node.right, S, curr_path, cache, result)

        return result

    return helper(root, S, 0, cache, 0)
```

Basically I don't understand why the recursive function is not updating my **result** variable but its updating my **cache** variable.

**Is there a correct way to update the result variable?**

This is the test case

```
count_paths(root, 11)
```

I printed each line of the results

```
node: 12, curr: 12, prev: 1
{0: 1, 12: 1}
0
node: 7, curr: 19, prev: 8
{0: 1, 12: 1, 19: 1}
0
node: 4, curr: 23, prev: 12
{0: 1, 12: 1, 19: 1, 23: 1}
1
node: 1, curr: 13, prev: 2
{0: 1, 12: 1, 19: 1, 23: 1, 13: 1}
0
node: 10, curr: 23, prev: 12
{0: 1, 12: 1, 19: 1, 23: 2, 13: 1}
1
node: 5, curr: 18, prev: 7
{0: 1, 12: 1, 19: 1, 23: 2, 13: 1, 18: 1}
0
Tree has paths: 0
```

Can someone please explain what I am missing here? I have a feeling I am making a fundamental recursion mistake here. I know I make a class and just store the variable there but I am really find to understand how to do recursion properly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Because you are *not* changing `cache` (that is, it is still the same object), you are changing what is *in* `cache`.

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks for clearing that up! Is there a way to update the result variable?

Comment: I do not believe there is a way to update an `int`.  If you put it in some kind of container (say, a `dict`), then you could update it the same way you do your cache.

Comment: Okay thanks that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tldr:

Python defaults to pass by reference, but since integers are immutable, it's like those are passed by copy. The easiest workaround here would be something like `result += helper(...), or result = helper(...)`.

Long answer:

In many languages (like C++ and Java), passing arguments defaults to passing copies of those objects. If you want to pass an object into a function and have it updated for use outside that function's context, you have to pass a pointer (or something similar).

Python, on the other hand, defaults to pass by reference. This would make you think your `result` variable would be updated in place, right?

The problem is that `result`, being an integer, is immutable. So, when you change its value within one of the recursive calls, it doesn't change the `result` variable for the other calls. It just reassigns the label `result` to a new integer value, *but only in that function call's scope.* The new value is lost once the function returns.

If you want to update an integer variable's value with a function call, you have to either set the variable to the return value of the function (see tldr above), or wrap the integer in a mutable object (see [Passing an integer by reference in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148496/passing-an-integer-by-reference-in-python)).