# Namedtuple is implemented with a verbose typename

Tags: python

Namedtuple is amaziing, but this question confusing me for a long time.

In the python docs [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
collections.namedtuple(typename, field_names, *, rename=False, defaults=None, module=None)
```

It's Basic exmaple as

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
EmployeeRecord = namedtuple('EmployeeRecord', 'name, age, title, department, paygrade')
```

I think it's more facile and tuple-like to define a namedtuple as

```
Point = namedtuple(['x', 'y'])
EmployeeRecord = namedtuple('name, age, title, department, paygrade')
```

What's the reason that `namedtuple` should be implementd with a verbose `typename`?

Comment: Think about it. How would you're `namedtuple` class know what its name is suppose to be?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

Comment: anonymous function could know its name by `name = lambda x:x*x` @ChristianDean

Comment: @Tool Then it's no longer an anonymous function, just bad practice. When you're naming lambdas, just write a function. Anyway, besides the point...

Comment: So, I get the point, function can be implemented anonymously, while class cannot. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: @Tool that lambda still doesn't have a distinctive `__name__` attribute because you aren't supposed to care about that. `func = lambda x:x; print(function.__name__)` will give you `'<lambda>'`. However, with a namedtuple you get a nice `__repr__` like `Point(x=0, y=0)`, which is a lot nicer than some canned `<namedtuple>(x=0,y=0)`

Comment: And you *could* have an anonymous type, or at least, a type whose name is an [empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123000/does-python-have-anonymous-classes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)  but while anonymous functions are sometimes useful/expedient, anonymous types are not. And since Python doesn't force you to write a class definition for everything, there really is no need for anonymous classes.

Comment: Finally, remeber, `namedtuple` isn't returning *a namedtuple* it's returning a type/class, so it shouldn't resemble the `tuple` constructor