# Is there a type hint to go with SimpleNamespace?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Say I am defining a function that returns a [types.SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace). I would like to type-hint the result:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

def func() -> SimpleNamespace(x: int, y: str):  # SyntaxError! What should be used instead?
    return SimpleNamespace(x=3, y='abc')
```

Note that `SimpleNamespace` is commonly used as alternative to `tuple` in which data members are named. For tuples, a corresponding type hint exists:

```
from typing import Tuple

def func() -> Tuple[int, str]:  # OK
    return 3, 'abc'
```

BTW, today I am using the following for documentation's sake:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

def func() -> SimpleNamespace(x=int, y=str):  # Seems to work fine
    return SimpleNamespace(x=3, y='abc')
```

But this is not standard (so it won't be supported by type checkers), and perhaps not proper Python (or is it?).

Comment: The type I'd merely `SimpleNamespace`

Comment: "Note that SimpleNamespace is commonly used as alternative to tuple in which data members are named. " No it isn't. It is really not a good replacement for a `tuple`, use a `NamedTuple` instead, or just a regular class (maybe a dataclass to avoid boilerplate).

Comment: @Carcigenicate: (1) You are indicating that SimpleNamespace is not like tuple in that it is mutable -- indeed correct, but still the question remains in case one would like a mutable object, or if one prefers the benefits of named data members.

Comment: @Carcigenicate @juanpa.arrivillaga You are suggesting `NamedTuple` and `dataclass` as alternatives. Indeed they have named data members (check), both support type hinting (check), `NamedTuple` is even immutable and extends type `tuple` if one would like that, but _both define a new type by name_. I don't want to define a new type every time a function returns more than a single value (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123000/does-python-have-anonymous-classes)).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga As for using `SimpleNamespace` as the type hint -- it is like using `tuple` as a type hint instead of the elaborate `Tuple[int, str]`.

Comment: @amk66 from the docs: `Changed in version 3.9: Attribute order in the repr changed from alphabetical to insertion (like dict).` Are you using python <3.9?

Comment: @aerijman I don't see how are `repr` and attribute order related to this question.

Comment: @amk66 `def func() -> SimpleNamespace(x=int, y=str):  # Seems to work fine` but `def func() -> SimpleNamespace(x: int, y: str):  # SyntaxError! What should be used instead?`. The first IS proper Python for version 3.3 to 3.9. The second is for >3.9 and I assume that your python is <3.9. If this does not answer your question, I missunderstood it and I apologize.

Comment: @amka66 you are asking for something that doesn't exist in python: " I don't want to define a new type every time a function returns more than a single value", although note, in equivalent constructs in other languages, e.g Scala, you would literally be creating a new type. Why don't you want to create a new type? Now, `SimpleNamespace` could support something like what you want, but it doesn't, so maybe open an issue? I suspect people will just suggest you use `NamedTuple` or another custom class, though.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree the standard library may support it, in case it doesn't (say, implementing `__getitem__` for `SimpleNamespace`) . As for defining a new `NamedTuple` every time a function returns more than a single value – this will result in _two_ definitions per function, and _two_ new identifiers per function, which IMHO is too cumbersome and overwhelming, especially if there is another option...

Comment: @aerijman I tried python 3.9 and still syntax error on `SimpleNamespace(x: int, y: str)`. Are you saying this is valid syntax in python 3.10? (i am not sure i understand)